# Are there gaussian random variables with non-linear dependence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Dependence does not mean correlation. Two random variables X and Y can be dependent in a non linear way (for instance, X is Beta and Y is X squared) so that their correlation coefficient is zero.

Can exist two gaussians X and Y which are dependent but with zero linear correlation coefficient?

Dependence between gaussians is everywhere modeled as linear e.g. one variable is $(\mu_x  + \sigma_x X)$ and the other one is $(Y = \mu_y + \sigma_y(\rho X + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}))$.

But is there a theorem which says this is the **only** type of dependence between gaussians that exists? Or just for simplicity is it the most utilized?

Comment: Wikipedia even has a page named exactly "Normally distributed and uncorrelated does not imply independent" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent

Comment: Conditional linearity gives the bivariate normal, which is simple and have nice properties and thus most of the elementary materials will talk about this. But this does not restrict us to model any other arbitrary dependency. One can pick a copula and put different univariate normal CDF inside, and then generate a multivariate CDF which the underlying joint distribution have normal marginals but equip with arbitrary dependency, depending on the choice of the copula.